# how to control addition and substraction on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do count clicking by button and I want to add if else statement if `.kisi-sayi-text` value is = 0 don't add but nothing happend on my code

HTML

```
<div class="count-box yetiskin-count">
        <span class="count-text">Yetişkin:</span>
        <span class="kisi-down"></span>
        <span class="kisi-sayi-text">1</span>
        <span class="kisi-up"></span>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.yetiskin-count > .kisi-up').on("click",function(){
  var topParents = $(this).parents(".yetiskin-count"),
      kisiSayiText   = topParents.find(".kisi-sayi-text"),
      kisiSayiNumber = kisiSayiText.html(parseInt($(".kisi-sayi-text").html())+1);

     if(kisiSayiNumber<0){
        return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: Use this simple code https://jsfiddle.net/8wss6b58/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is not within the `.kisi-up` click event, you should look at the `.kisi-down` click handler as it handles the subtraction so it will stop subtracting when it reaches 0.

```js
$('.yetiskin-count > .kisi-up').on("click",function(){
     var topParents = $(this).parents(".yetiskin-count"),
       kisiSayiText = topParents.find(".kisi-sayi-text"),
       kisiSayiNumber = parseInt($(".kisi-sayi-text").html());
     kisiSayiText.html(kisiSayiNumber + 1);
});

$('.yetiskin-count > .kisi-down').on("click",function(){
     var topParents = $(this).parents(".yetiskin-count"),
       kisiSayiText = topParents.find(".kisi-sayi-text"),
       kisiSayiNumber = parseInt($(".kisi-sayi-text").html());
     if(kisiSayiNumber <= 0){
        return false;
     }
     kisiSayiText.html(kisiSayiNumber - 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-box yetiskin-count">
        <span class="count-text">Yetişkin:</span>
        <span class="kisi-down">&lt;</span>
        <span class="kisi-sayi-text">1</span>
        <span class="kisi-up">&gt;</span>
    </div>
```

Compare this:

```
$('.yetiskin-count > .kisi-up').on("click",function(){
  var topParents = $(this).parents(".yetiskin-count"),
      kisiSayiText   = topParents.find(".kisi-sayi-text"),
      kisiSayiNumber = kisiSayiText.html(parseInt($(".kisi-sayi-text").html())+1);

     // kisiSayiNumber is a jQuery object, not a number so there is no point comparing it with 0
     if(kisiSayiNumber<0){
        return false;
     }
});
```

with this:

```
$('.yetiskin-count > .kisi-up').on("click",function(){
  var topParents = $(this).parents(".yetiskin-count"),
      kisiSayiText = topParents.find(".kisi-sayi-text"),
      kisiSayiNumber = parseInt(kisiSayiText.html());

      // if the current running number is less than or equal to 0 then don't add
      if (kisiSayiNumber <= 0)
          return false;
      kisiSayiText.html(kisiSayiNumber + 1);
});
```

Comment: but I guess there is some issu if my number equal to 0 if I want to addition after that nothing happend

Comment: sorry but you have to clarify what is your expected outcome, like is it the number only goes from 0 to positive infinity?

Comment: no I mean if I want addition it must addition if I want substraction it must subscraction up 0

Comment: I have added a code snippet which may be what you intend to do

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this line

```
kisiSayiNumber = kisiSayiText.html(parseInt($(".kisi-sayi-text").html())+1);
```

with

```
kisiSayiNumber = kisiSayiText.html(parseInt($(".kisi-sayi-text").text())+1);
```

and i will start addition the way you want

Comment: While technically better, this will make no difference to the outcome and won't affect what the OP wants to do

Comment: First his syntax is being corrected and am posting full answer though

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `<span class="kisi-up"></span>`.. Try to put some data.

For example

`<span class="kisi-up">Click Me</span>`

Because you can't click the span `kisi-up`

```js
 $('.yetiskin-count > .kisi-up').on("click",function(){
  var topParents = $(this).parents(".yetiskin-count"),
      kisiSayiText   = topParents.find(".kisi-sayi-text"),
      kisiSayiNumber = kisiSayiText.html(parseInt($(".kisi-sayi-text").html())+1);

     if(kisiSayiNumber<0){
        return false;
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-box yetiskin-count">
        <span class="count-text">Yetişkin:</span>
        <span class="kisi-down"></span>
        <span class="kisi-sayi-text">1</span>
        <span class="kisi-up">Click Me</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('.yetiskin-count > .kisi-up').on("click",function(){
  
  var topParents = $(this).parents(".yetiskin-count");
    var  kisiSayiText   = topParents.find(".kisi-sayi-text");
      if($(".kisi-sayi-text").html()<=0){
        return false;
     };
      kisiSayiNumber = kisiSayiText.html(parseInt($(".kisi-sayi-text").html())+1);

     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count-box yetiskin-count">
        <span class="count-text">Yetişkin:</span>
        <span class="kisi-down"></span>
        <span class="kisi-sayi-text">1</span>
        <span class="kisi-up">click here</span>
    </div>
```

hi,
You need to have some content in the span tag to click on and make sure you include JQuery library. you can run the snippet to check functionality.
i hope this solves your problem.  happy coding!!!

Comment: this code works for less then or equal to zero condition